# My program is running but null value is coming at the end.how to remove this error in my program.Why it is coming?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
 <html lang="en-US"> 

  <script src= http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"/> <head> <meta charset="ISO-8859-1"> 
  <title>AngularJS_Index</title> </head>

 <body data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="productController"> 
   <table border=2> 
    <tr> 
      <th>ID</th> <th>Name</th> <th>Price</th> <th>Quantity</th> 
    </tr> 

    <tr data-ng-repeat="product in listProducts"> 

      <td>{{product.id}}</td> 
      <td>{{product.name}}</td> 
      <td>{{product.price}}</td> 
      <td>{{product.quantity}}</td> 

    </tr>
   </table> 

   <script type="text/javascript"> 
     var myapp=angular.module('myApp',[]) ;

     myapp.controller('productController',function($scope){ 

     $scope.listProducts=[ {id :'P01',name :'Milk',price : 40,quantity:10 } {id :'P02',name :'Butter',price :50,quantity:11 } {id :'P03',name :'Biscuits',price :60,quantity:12 } {id :'P04',name :'Chocolate',price :70,quantity:13 } ];

   });
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have corrected some mistakes.Please have a look into this working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/36ShkSuWk8Fz6cyV8eLG?p=preview).

```
var myapp=angular.module('myApp',[]) ;

myapp.controller('productController',function($scope){ 

$scope.listProducts=[ {id :'P01',name :'Milk',price : 40,quantity:10 }, {id :'P02',name :'Butter',price :50,quantity:11 }, {id :'P03',name :'Biscuits',price :60,quantity:12 } ,{id :'P04',name :'Chocolate',price :70,quantity:13 } ];

 });
```

Comment: i tried your code but it still showing output with double braces.
     
it also showing ' Undefind attribute names ng-app and ng controller '

Answer (score 0):

There were lot of syntactical errors in your application. Secondly, your angular referencing was wrong. Please check the below working example on plunker:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>AngularJS_Index</title>
 </head>

  <body>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <div ng-controller="productController">
      <table border="2">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
        </tr>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="product in listProducts">
          <td>{{product.id}}</td>
          <td>{{product.name}}</td>
          <td>{{product.price}}</td>
          <td>{{product.quantity}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var myapp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myapp.controller('productController', function($scope) {

  $scope.listProducts = [{
    id: 'P01',
    name: 'Milk',
    price: 40,
    quantity: 10
  }, {
    id: 'P02',
    name: 'Butter',
    price: 50,
    quantity: 11
  }, {
    id: 'P03',
    name: 'Biscuits',
    price: 60,
    quantity: 12
  }, {
    id: 'P04',
    name: 'Chocolate',
    price: 70,
    quantity: 13
  }];

});
```

[LINK](https://plnkr.co/edit/tYx6Zt4BMTUwTfY0Tnk6?p=preview)

Comment: its not working i dnt know why ? i am using eclipse mars. i copy your code and put same code as it is in my eclipse but still i am getting null pointer error as it print expression braces as it is.

Comment: ID                  Name                 Price                     Quantity 
{{product.id}} {{product.name}} {{product.price}} {{product.quantity}}

Comment: it also showing ' Undefind attribute names ng-app and ng controller ' .

Comment: Did you check the plunker link ? Could you add your code on plunker so that i can evaluate it ?

Comment: if you are using eclipse, use data-ng-app and data-ng-controller

Comment: i just check on plunker.it is running on plunker but not in eclipse mars.

Answer (score 0):

Seperate each object by `,` operator. your solution will work perfectly :

**Try :**

```
$scope.listProducts=[ {id :'P01',name :'Milk',price : 40,quantity:10 }, {id :'P02',name :'Butter',price :50,quantity:11 }, {id :'P03',name :'Biscuits',price :60,quantity:12 }, {id :'P04',name :'Chocolate',price :70,quantity:13 } ];
```

**Instead of :**

```
$scope.listProducts=[ {id :'P01',name :'Milk',price : 40,quantity:10 } {id :'P02',name :'Butter',price :50,quantity:11 } {id :'P03',name :'Biscuits',price :60,quantity:12 } {id :'P04',name :'Chocolate',price :70,quantity:13 } ];
```

**Output :**

[image]

**Working fiddle :** https://jsfiddle.net/Lt7aP/3374/

Thanks.

Comment: i tried your code but it still showing output with double braces.

Comment: it also showing ' Undefind attribute names ng-app and ng controller ' .

Comment: @RohitKhadatkar I updated the answer with working fiddle. please check